# Running unit tests right click context item not visible with IntelliJ 12

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I downloaded the latest intellij 12 release, and now I don't see that right click context menu item to run my unit test for the current file.

Where is that option now?

Comment: Works for me. Please share a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Working for me as well. Check your module's settings and make sure it's a Java project, it's using the correct JDK, etc; while I didn't have any issues with the upgrade, a friend had to muck with a few of his projects.

Comment: looks like somehow the project settings changed and my folder was not marked as a test folder any longer.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Since switching to IntelliJ 12, for JUnit annotated classes under src/test/java, the context menu does not show any of the run or debug options that are usually available.  I checked project structure and my src/test/java path is correctly designated as "Test Sources".  My workaround was to create a JUnit run configuration. Details: IntelliJ project is based on Maven multi-module project. The module is a Jersey REST service. (Maybe I upgraded to IntelliJ 12 a little too soon;-)

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm running on Mac OS 10.9 with JDK 1.6. I used to be able to do this in IDEA 11 but not 12 :( I've tried the suggestions below but it still doesn't work. While I can still set up unit tests from the Edit Configurations dialog, I really miss being able to quickly configure all my unit tests from the context menu... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason my project settings seemed to have not been picked up correctly with IntelliJ 12, I had to reset the /test folder as a test source and it works fine now.

Answer (score 12):

The solution which worked for me, is as follows...

Right click on the test folder------>Mark Directory AS------>select Test Source

Answer (score 12):

Just had the same issue in a maven project - I had forgotten to mark the test class as public which resolved it immediately.

Comment: +1 because your scenario is actually quite easy to occur:

Alt+enter in the class -> create test: IJ (2017.1.1) proposes Arquillian Junit as first option of testing library and by going with it the test class and methods are created without the 'public' identifier. Then if one decides to change the testing library to JUnit, it is easy to forget about the absence of the 'public' identifier, which causes the tests not to be recognised by IJ.

Answer (score 8):

I also had this problem under IDEA 14.1.4 but JUnit plugin was on. 
After some time spent on comparing my old **{HOME}/.IdeaIC14** folder and newly created one, I've discovered that problem lies in AntDebugger v1.2.0 plugin. Uninstalling it helped.

So if anyone still have problems with run item in context menu maybe it's because of some underdeveloped plugin.

Comment: Hejwo is my HERO!  I've been banging my head on this intermittently for a year. Disabling the Ant Debugger 1.2.0 plugin and restarting intellij worked for me. I'm gonna report it to Jetbrains.

Comment: Perfect Perfect answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add junit plugin.
Preferences -> plugins -> junit.[image: add junit plugin]

Answer (score 2):

Test sources were marked correctly in my case.
File -> Invalidate Caches -> Restart did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was to put the test files inside a separate directory. Moreover, the test directory should be located OUTSIDE the src directory. Then, I had the right click menu item to mark the directory as test. Finally, I had to make both the test method and class containing it 'public' and also the method had to be 'public void'.

I have no idea where are all these restrictions documented. I am new to Java and JUnit, anyway.

Comment: Thank you!  My class was not public!  I had translated from Groovy and didn't even notice that the class was not public.  Now my context menu contains Run and Debug as it should.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue occurred because of the Node plugin; disabling it fixed the issue; after a restart of IntelliJ, my Run options were back.

I could identify the issue by looking at IntelliJ's logs, where there were NoSuchMethod errors when I right clicked on a test class/method name.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled IntelliJ on mac and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in IDEA 14.1.4.  Somehow, my JUnit plugin became disabled in Settings --> Plugins.  I re-enabled it and am back in business.

Answer (score 0):

That means IntelliJ was not able to configure your workspace as python workspace. It generally shows a message when it detects python scripts and provide an auto configure option like "configure python". This message was not appearing when I was opening python workspace and hence no tests were getting identified.

I faced this issue when working simultaneously between Java and Python unit tests. The caching might have prevented identification of unit tests in python workspace.

I just restarted cache using the option available in File menu (IntelliJ IDEA) and it reconfigured python as soon as I opened my python workspace after cache restarted.

Answer (score 0):

For those new to IntelliJ, you'll also get this issue if you accidentally create your Java file outside of the src folder. Moving it back in will fix it.